# Connection to virtual machine from host machine is depend on internet connectivity

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm using VM fusion for macOS and running VM machine that's connected to external network using NAT protocol.

The connectivity to the host machine is going through the virtual bridge interface

```
bridge100: flags=8a63<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,ALLMULTI,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
        ether 8a:55:a:b1:27:64
        inet 192.168.21.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.21.255
        inet6 fe80::ab1:b172:333:2ff8%bridge100 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x14
        Configuration:
                id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
                maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
                root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
                ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
        member: en8 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
                ifmaxaddr 0 port 19 priority 0 path cost 0
        nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
        media: autoselect
        status: active
```

My Question is how come that whenever the external physical interface for internet connection is down (can be wi-fi or ethernet), so does the connectivity with the virtual machine... Theoretically those should be decoupled.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: VMware Workstation has (or had, haven’t used it in years) a feature to replicate physical connection state. Maybe VMware Fusion has it too?

Comment: But what does it good for ? Ideally I'd like to be able to communicate my VM even when the external connection is off.

Comment: I can connect to my VM in Workstation for Windows when the host network is down. I just tried it. Can you reset the VMware Network Editor (this will reset NAT and you should then restart both guest and host).